# Login associated with Stack Overflow account got deleted

Tags: support, stack-overflow, login

Scenario: I have created an account with my company email since others like Gmail, or Facebook are blocked and I had to use my company mail to login. Then, I switched companies and forget to add an additional login. My previous company's email account got deleted and now I am unable to access my account.

1. In above situation what should I do?
2. Which information should I provide to get my account back?

Comment: @jonsca please add this comment as answer so that i can accept it

Comment: You got it, glad you got it fixed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to use [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/defunct), which is accessible via the Contact Us link in the footer of the Stack Overflow page. It's designed to be used when an OpenID provider disappears, but you're basically the same situation.

If that doesn't solve the issue, email team@stackoverflow.com directly and explain your situation, giving your old email address (and your old userID number from your profile if you still have it).

Comment: This was moved from a comment.

Comment: yup ....i got it exactly .... thankyou...